# Solve equation using Laplace

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, problem-solving, laplace-transform

I am trying to solve the following differential equation using Laplace and am not sure where I am going wrong: $$\frac{\text{d}^2x}{\text{d}t^2} + 2\frac{\text{d}x}{\text{d}t} + 5x=0,$$ where $x(0)=1$ and $\dot x(0)=0$.
$$\mathbf{L}\left[\frac{\text{d}^2x}{\text{d}t^2} + 2\frac{\text{d}x}{\text{d}t} + 5x=0\right]=\mathbf{L}[0]$$

Then $$s^2X(s) - sx(0) - \dot x(0) + 2(sX(s)-x(0)) + 5X(s)= 0$$

Then $$X(s)= \dfrac{2+s}{s^2+2s+5}$$

What do I do next please and is this even correct? I don’t think it is as the denominator can’t be factorised?

Comment: Hi, thank you. I tried it, but the denominator doesn’t factorise? And why did you split it up like that please? With 1 and s+1 on top please?

Comment: Hi Moo. Ill try it again, thanks for the help

Comment: Hi thanks a lot! I didn’t actually ever go that far in the table, but I have now! Thank you! Sorry what do you mean by you can skip and use formal definition please to find inverse? So by integrating that fraction multiplied by e^-st please?

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot Moo!